# second order accurate scheme for finding derivatives

Tags: python

So I'm doing a class project and have to plot a numerical approximation of the derivative of `f(x)=x*arctan(x)` using the second order accurate scheme,
`f(xi) ≈(f(xi+1) − f(xi−1))/2h`
oh and also plot `f(x)`

I've done this so far:

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pylab import *
a=0
b=2
n=100
h=(b-a)/n
def f(x):
    f=x*arctan(x)
    return(f)
def dydx(x):
    d=(f(x+h)-f(x-h))/2*h
    return(d)
x=linspace(a,b,n+1)
plot(x,f(x),'b')
plot(x,dydx(x),'r--')
```

the problem i am receiving is that the graph for my derivative is coming out at a significantly lesser value than it should be (i.e limit at `0.0006`instead of `1.6`) - how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not the brightest light when it comes to math problems, so I might misunderstand your question, but the problem couldn't perhaps be that you simply forgot to place 2*h inside of some parenthesis?

So instead of: `d=(f(x+h)-f(x-h))/2*h`
Try: `d=(f(x+h)-f(x-h))/(2*h)`

Comment: that's literally it - thank you!!! that's embarrassingly simple haha

Comment: @SophiePalmer been there done that ;) nothing to worry about